# Hibernate transaction time out event

Tags: java, hibernate, transactions

How can i do something on transaction timeout in hibernate.

I want to set a transaction timeout before , and if the transaction doesn't complete before the set time i have to do something .

is there any event like on timeout or something. How can i do this. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A RuntimeException is thrown, so catch it to do anything.

Take a look to http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#transactions-demarcation-timeout